# No theming on buttons when embedding IE9

Tags: themes, internet-explorer-9, embedding

I'm using the IWebBrowser2 interface to IE9 in a standard Win32 app. Pages with controls like buttons are rendered without theming, so look like something from the Windows 2000 era. The identical page displays correctly using the stand-alone IE9. All pages have

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

in the header

Any thoughts?

[image: Unthemed button snap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement `IDocHostUIHandler`, then in the method `GetHostInfo` append the `DOCHOSTUIFLAG_THEME` to the `dwFlags`:

```
STDMETHODIMP GetHostInfo(DOCHOSTUIINFO *pInfo)
{
    pInfo->cbSize = sizeof(DOCHOSTUIINFO);
    pInfo->dwFlags = DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NO3DBORDER|DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DIALOG|DOCHOSTUIFLAG_THEME;
    pInfo->dwDoubleClick = DOCHOSTUIDBLCLK_DEFAULT;
    return S_OK;
}
```